# Interacting with the parent component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been thinking about a certain abstraction that I want to create in my codebase, which would eliminate a lot of boilerplate. The question I have is about the most "correct" way to achieve an interaction between child and parent classes.

We have a lot of `<table />`s which I want to abstract into a sort of `<Table />` component. The reason for this is that we have a lot of boilerplate to do with sortable headers, pagination, etc.. Every time we implement a new table, there's a lot of copy-pasting and a lot of extra testing which should really be abstracted away.

My ideal pattern would be something like:

```
<Table>
    <Table.Header>
        <Table.SortableHeader dataKey="id" default>ID</Table.SortableHeader>
        <Table.SortableHeader dataKey="name">Name</Table.SortableHeader>
        // ...
    </Table.Header>
    <Table.PaginatedBody pageSize=15 rowElement={ MyRowElement } />
</Table>
```

In order to do this, the `<Table.SortableHeader>` components need to be able to set the state (or otherwise interact) with the parent `<Table>` component in order to change its sort key/order, and the sort key/order needs to be passed down to the `<Table.PaginatedBody>` component.

Furthermore, the `<Table.SortableHeader>` components needs to know the current sort key/order as they will display different depending on whether the sort key is the same as their `dataKey` and also if the sort order is `asc` or `desc`.

One way I thought of doing this was by passing the parent component down in the `context` (I know new context-based stuff has come out but this is a more general question of principle).

Does this method throw up any obvious problems, and are there any other standard methods for doing this sort of thing? I want to avoid having configuration objects which I pass down to a `<GenericTable />` component which will then generate the structure, as I feel like JSX is a perfectly good DSL for creating view elements, and this is a lot cleaner.

Comment: I might suggest you take a look at one of the approaches from react-virtualized implementation: [Table](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Table.md) and [Column](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Column.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your sort handler in your `Table` component and add it to it's children props along with the sort state. This way `Header` components can call the parent sort handler to update the `Table` state, which will then pass down the sort state to the `Header` props.

You can use `cloneElement` to add props to `children` :

```
{ React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    sort: this.state.sort,
    handleSort: this.handleSort
  });
})}
```

Full sample code : https://codesandbox.io/s/926nj5r6jw

Comment: Ah using element cloning, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Could you add your example as a code snippet instead of just a link and I'll mark this as the correct answer (I used this method)